# Interpreting results of Granger causality test

Tags: python, time-series, causality

I've done all the pre-processing on my data and am conducting Granger causality using statsmodels. However, I am confused as to how to interpret the significance of the result when I have multiple lags that reject the Null (pscore <.05). Ideally I'd like to know what the 'optimal' number of lags is in my time series. Is it mathematically plausible to simply take the lowest pscore, in this case, 1 lag, and say that X2 Granger causes X1 by 1 lag?

```
Granger Causality
number of lags (no zero) 1
ssr based F test:         F=15.8650 , p=0.0004  , df_denom=31, df_num=1
ssr based chi2 test:   chi2=17.4003 , p=0.0000  , df=1
likelihood ratio test: chi2=14.0516 , p=0.0002  , df=1
parameter F test:         F=15.8650 , p=0.0004  , df_denom=31, df_num=1

Granger Causality
number of lags (no zero) 2
ssr based F test:         F=8.3979  , p=0.0014  , df_denom=28, df_num=2
ssr based chi2 test:   chi2=19.7949 , p=0.0001  , df=2
likelihood ratio test: chi2=15.5070 , p=0.0004  , df=2
parameter F test:         F=8.3979  , p=0.0014  , df_denom=28, df_num=2

Granger Causality
number of lags (no zero) 3
ssr based F test:         F=5.4257  , p=0.0052  , df_denom=25, df_num=3
ssr based chi2 test:   chi2=20.8348 , p=0.0001  , df=3
likelihood ratio test: chi2=16.0459 , p=0.0011  , df=3
parameter F test:         F=5.4257  , p=0.0052  , df_denom=25, df_num=3

Granger Causality
number of lags (no zero) 4
ssr based F test:         F=3.6572  , p=0.0198  , df_denom=22, df_num=4
ssr based chi2 test:   chi2=20.6135 , p=0.0004  , df=4
likelihood ratio test: chi2=15.8037 , p=0.0033  , df=4
parameter F test:         F=3.6572  , p=0.0198  , df_denom=22, df_num=4
```

Comment: This might be a better questions for stats.stackexchange.com, as it pertains mostly to statistics, and there is no concrete, underlying programming question.

Comment: @dcsuka thanks for the advice! I will also post on stats